# Rename js files in maven build process with sha1/md5

Tags: javascript, maven, maven-3

I need to versioning my javascript files and think the best way is to generate the sha1/md5 of each file and rename it with that result (and the reference to each js file too obviously) during the build process.

This way, when a file content changes, its name changes too and I have not to worry about versioning anymore.

I am trying to find some info about how to make this works with maven but I don't find anything related to.

Any help?

Comment: What about version control systems - they don't meet your requirement?

Comment: I am using GIT but the problem is related to caching into the client browser. I have been using version names (aka file-v1.0.0, file-v1.0.1) but i would like a more consistent and automatized way to handle this.

Comment: For testing you could test with browsers in incognito mode, if not using automated tools. For deployment, you could suffix with maven `version` value.